# Why am I getting an Error with TADOQuery select statement?

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, ado, delphi-2010

Every time that I try to set the caption of this variable, it gives me "unspecified error" and I have concluded...

I've tried to set the caption straight from the TADOQuery and by assigning the value to a variable then loading it to the caption, but either way I get an unspecified error.

```pascal
    qry1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Number of Games Owned FROM Users WHERE UserID = "' + sLoggedInUser + '";';
    qry1.Open;
    iCountGames := qry1['Number of Games Owned'];
    lblUserGamesOwned.Caption := 'Games Owned: ' + IntToStr(iCountGames);
```

Database design:

```
Field Name               Data Type         Description
UserID                   Short Text        Maximum characters is 6
FirstName                Short Text        Maximum characters is 25
LastName                 Short Text        Maximum characters is 25
Cell Number              Short Text        Maximum characters is 10
Number of Games Owned    Number            Integer
```

I expect the code to load the value into the variable, and then the variable is used to set the caption of the TLabel, but all that happens is the unspecified error pops up, and the TLabel stays unchanged.

Comment: And please for the love of [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/), get into the habit of using parameters.

Comment: You are really pushing the limits here, I thought the name of your column is just for asking purposes, but looking to the accepted answer you were actually for real. You will fall in a lot of pit holes, if you kept coding like this. After all computer are dumb and you should treat them as such. You should use variables/tools ( AS operator) that are designed for this and stop killing us with you

Comment: I am sorry to say that ms access actually encourage you to use such field names if you let it do things automatically or use its wizards to build tables. Not to mention object names in your native language...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine that you just need braces around the column name:

```
SELECT [Number of Games Owned] FROM Users WHERE UserID = "' + sLoggedInUser + '";';
```

I would also recommend that you use parameters to pass in `UserId` rather than munging the query string.

Comment: Thank you! The `[]` around the field name solved it. Don't know why I didn't try that...

Comment: @Andog Best practice, if you get to design the database, is to simply avoid spaces in your field names.  It just adds unnecessary complication.

Comment: @Andog Also shouldn't have that large of a field name. And by the looks of it, you're going about this all wrong. I'm assuming you have some other table of "Games" owned by each user. Why not simply include a count from that table instead of that field?